# Show Map on click, then scrolllTo map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm not sure why is no working the scroll to the map function. I'm using the scroll animation

On click it SHOULD scroll to the map

Please have a look my jsfiddle, it quite strait forward.

http://jsfiddle.net/wLs1u3bv/

js:

```
var scrollToLondon = $("a.London");
var getLondon = new google.maps.LatLng('51.515502', '-0.078345');
var slideMap = $('#map-canvas');
var body = $("#map-canvas");
slideMap.addClass('close');


function initializeLondon() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 18,
        center: getLondon,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var contentString = '<address class="address">address goes here</address>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });
    var image = 'assets/images/marker-red.png';
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: getLondon,
        map: map,
        title: 'London',
        icon: image
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
}

var myDiv = document.getElementById("London");
google.maps.event.addDomListener(myDiv, "click", function () {

    initializeLondon();
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeLondon);


    slideMap.removeClass('close');
    body.animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 800);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: trigger the resize event on the map when the animation finishes (it has zero size before that).

Comment: @geocodezip i've just modified the codepen, so u saying to trigger the resize event with the scroll inside?

Comment: @geocodezip would u be able to give e more deep help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wLs1u3bv/2/)**

try using

`$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 800 }, "slow");`

Now your London click function will be like

```
$('#London').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    initializeLondon();
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 800 }, "slow"); 
    return false;
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeLondon);

});
```

Comment: tanks dude, really pleased with that

Comment: @user3699998 : Am glad , that my answer helps you